# Xamarin forms navigation bar color

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using tabbed page inside navigation page, which is inside MasterDetail.Detail.
I've used following line of code.
Detail = new NavigationPage(MyTabbedPage);
But the color of the navigation bar is white !

Is there any way to change the color ???
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NavigationPage navigationPage = new NavigationPage(mainPageView);
    navigationPage.BarBackgroundColor = MyNavigationBarBackgroundColor;
    navigationPage.BarTextColor = MyNavigationBarTextColor;
```

Comment: It still is in white color :(

Answer (score 0):

This one helps you

**App.xaml.cs**

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage()) { 
            BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("a9cd44"),
            BarTextColor = Color.Black
        };
    }
```